Server doesn't recognize Ethernet in Netplan configuration
I'm very new to Ubuntu, Linux, Netplan, and using the terminal at all. I'm running an Ubuntu 24.04 server on a Raspberry Pi 5, which is hooked up to Ethernet via cable.
According to >ip a, The device is connected to lo, eth0, and wlan0. The server's Netplan configuration file (/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml) doesn't seem to notice that there's Ethernet, and doesn't look like any of the pictures of Netplan config files I see online.
Example of what I think my config file SHOULD look like:
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        enp3s0:
            dhcp4: true

What my config file currently looks like:
network:
    version: 2
    wifis:
        renderer: networkd
        wlan0:
            access-points:
                fishnet:    #wifi network name
                    password: [redacted]
            dhcp4: true
            optional: true

I'm trying to set up a static IP, but I'm having trouble as the config doesn't look like any config in any of the tutorials I see, most notably in that it has no reference to Ethernet, so there's nowhere to define an address. Other than this, the server works fine.
I've tried >netplan generate, manually changing the file to look like the ones I see online, just adding an addresses spot in the wifis and wlan0 sections, rebooting the server, unplugging/replugging the Ethernet cable, running a completely new instance of Ubuntu on a different SD card (and all of the above on that new instance). None have produced a result other than disconnecting my ssh.
My end goal is to establish a static IP for this server. Why doesn't my Netplan configuration file look like the ones I see online? How can I get it to?

The Netplan instructions answer precisely this question: https://netplan.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/#how-to-configure-a-static-ip-address-on-an-interface

You are correct. You have a WIFI section, but no Ethernet section.
If you wish to combine (you want Wifi and Ethernet), it would look similar to this (for static IP Ethernet and dynamic IP wifi):
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        enp3s0:
             addresses:
                 - 10.10.10.10/24
    wifis:
        renderer: networkd
        wlan0:
            access-points:
                fishnet:
                    password: passwordhere
            dhcp4: true
            optional: true

To verify the network device (such as 'enp3s0' and 'wlan0') is correct in each section, use lshw -c network.

To find the name of your Ethernet adapter, run:
ip link show

This will give you a list - on my Raspberry Pi 4, it looks like:
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:9a:15:72 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:9a:15:74 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

In your case the wlan0 will be up, but the ethernet eth0 (or what the name is) is down.
The main point here is to get the correct device name for the Ethernet adapter, which may or may not be eth0.
When you have the correct name (given as eth0 here for example's sake) edit your netplan config.
To use DHCP to assign a random or static IP (configured in your DHCP server), use this config: (this is actually how my config is, because the IP is set statically by DHCP)
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: true

To hardcode the IP on the device instead of via DHCP, use this config:
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      addresses:
        - xxx.yyy.zzz.IP/24
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: xxx.yyy.zzz.1
      nameservers:
          addresses: [<primary DNS>, <secondary DNS>]

Where xxx.yyy.zzz.IP is the desired IP of your device, and xxx.yyy.zzz.1 is the IP of your gateway.
Configurations are applied with sudo netplan apply.
These examples are for Ethernet only, where the wireless adapter will be disabled (which is logical for a server).
Configuration is documented here and here.
